# Are Identity Columns kept after recreation of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

A table has multiple columns, including one Identity column. If a columnn is added in the middle of this table, the table needs to be recreated. Are the Identities that were assigned before kept, or is this reset?

I tried it for a small dummy table and there the identities were kept. But I wonder if this is always the case?
Thank you !

Comment: The script that migrates data from the old table to the new one is responsible for retaining existing `IDENTITY` values, using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` with an explicit column list in the `INSERT` statement. Add the script to your question for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: "in the middle of this table" -> why wouldn't you just add the column and not worry about its physical location? Then no rebuild is necessary at all. "I tried it" -> how? By changing the table in table designer UI and letting SSMS rebuild it? I wouldn't do that for a large table.

Comment: SQL Server itself does not allow adding a column to be added anywhere in the middle of the table. What tool are you using to create these scripts? SSMS? SSDT?

Comment: You can only *add* a column to the "end" of a table. If you are using SSMS designer, it generates a acript to drop and recreate the table; as you already noted it preserves 100% of the data. The ordinal position of a column should not and does not affect how you query a table.

Comment: *"If a columnn is added in the middle of this table, the table needs to be recreated."*  Just don't do this, just `ADD` the column to the `TABLE` and the column will appear at the end. If the ordinal positions of the columns really matter, then you control that in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Dropping and recreating a table so you can add a column in the middle is fraught with danger and a habit you want to break as soon as possible. Identity columns are often used for primary key constraints, so they're often targets for foreign key references from multiple tables. If you're drop-create happy then you're also going to have to drop all of those foreign key constraints beforehand and recreate them afterwards.

Comment: Even better, i think SSMS by default (or at all?) doesn't recreate schemabound view primary keys when you do the "column move around thing", hit me a few times

Comment: @siggemannen I think you mean indexed views

Comment: Exactly, @Charlieface :D It creates the view again, but for some reasons, not the indices

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback so far.
Some things I want to point out:
 - I know adding a column to the end of the table is best practice, which I always try to follow
- Yes you can add a column in the middle using SSMS 'design tool', for very large tables this doesn't work however as the memory is not sufficient in most cases to keep the data while recreating the table
- My question origins because someone from our department added this column and wondered if we had to rerun the DWH because or keys might / might not be changed because of this.